# MIME types and ACTION_SEND intent chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using very standard code to send images from my app.  A user emailed me that their default messaging app doesn't show up in the chooser, and oddly enough the same happens on my phone.  I was playing around with the MIME type of the intent.  `"text/plain"` shows a set of options including my Messages app, and `"*/*"` shows a ton.  Would I be lazy to set the MIME type to `"*/*"` so that I don't get filtered by apps that should be an option for the user to send images?  Or is that pretty much the way to go?

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Custom Heading..."));
```

One side effect of this that I don't like is that a few apps (Facebook, Handcent) have multiple intents registered to send various MIME types, so they show up in the list more than once when the MIME type is `"*/*"`.

Answer (score 4):

The built in messaging should handle your mime type, so it may be a platform specific issue:

```
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
       </intent-filter>
```

[Check out the source for all the mime types that are handled](http://code.google.com/p/modified-android-mms/source/browse/trunk/AndroidManifest.xml?spec=svn3&r=3).